# cant map through json array imported from mongodb using mongoose

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I´m new to using React and are currently doing a porject in school.
My problem is I have setup a api js file which connect to mongodb database and I have also a route to the collection. 
Then In ReactContext I try to fetch the collection and that works. My problem is when I try to render it from my MovieList component I get "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" I have console logged my json and I get the documents of the collection but somehow when it ReactContext returns it, it gets undefined?

Code:

````
      //  let response = await fetch('/api/movies/')
      //  response = await response.json()
      //  return response
      var response = await fetch('/api/movies/')
      var data = await response.json()
      console.log(data)
      return data
    }

    const test = () => {
        let data = getMovies()
        console.log(data)
    }

    const [movies2, setMovies2] = useState(getMovies)

    return (
        <MovieContext.Provider value={{movies2}}>
            {props.children}
        </MovieContext.Provider>
    ) ```
Can someone see what the problem is?
When I used a dummy data in a const variable with the data it works.

This is the code which calls "map()".
```const list = () => {
        return movies.map((movie, i) => {
            return (
                <Card
                    key={movie.title + i}
                    body
                    inverse
                    className="mb-2"
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: '#330000',
                        borderColor: '#FF0000'
                    }}
                >
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <img style={{
                            height: '100px'
                        }}  
                        src={movie.image} 
                        alt="movie"></img>
                        <Col>
                            <CardTitle>Titel: <br></br>{ movie.title }</CardTitle>
                            <CardText>Om: <br></br>{ movie.about }</CardText>
                            <CardText>Åldersgräns: <br></br>{ movie.age_limit }</CardText>
                            <CardText>Längd: <br></br>{ movie.length }</CardText>
                            <CardText>Pris: <br></br>{ movie.ticket_price }</CardText>
                            <div>
                                <ModalVideo channel='youtube' isOpen={isOpen} videoId={movie.movieTrailer} onClose={toggleIsOpen} />
                                <Button onClick={toggleIsOpen}>Spela Trailer</Button>
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
                </Card>
            )
        })
    }```
````

Comment: can you post the code where the map function is called?

Comment: Try a console.log of movies2 right underneath the const [movies2, setMovies2] = useState(getMovies) line.

Comment: Where is the declaration of "movies"?

Comment: I see you have set movies2 as a state but called map function on movies

Comment: when I console log movies 2 I get ``` Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(8) ```

Comment: My declaration of movies is at the top of MovieList.js the same file as "const MovieList" I just import it as "import { MovieContext } from '../contexts/MovieContextProvider'"

Comment: So that is your first problem. You need to make sure that you dont try to render a mapped result while it is loading. 

And step 2, you need to create a proper consumer of the context, ref @RobertFedus comment

Comment: When I try to map over movies 2 I get "movies2.map is not a function"

Comment: Can you please post your `getMovies` function?

Comment: my getMovies function : "const getMovies = async () => {
        let response = await fetch('/api/movies/')
        response = await response.json()
        return response
    }"